# Consulta COUNT(*) Personalizada en FacadeREST

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, rest, get

estoy realizando una aplicación y aprendiendo cosillas sobre los servicios REST. El caso es que quiero hacer en el REST de mi entidad "Entrada", un GET para que me devuelva el count de las entradas de un determinado evento pero no me funciona :(

```
@GET
@Path("/entradasVendidas/{idEvento}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public int entradasVendidas(@PathParam("idEvento") Integer idEvento) {
    int vendidas = -1;

    try{
    vendidas = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Entrada e WHERE e.evento = :evento", Integer.class)
            .setParameter("evento", idEvento).getSingleResult();        
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return vendidas;

}
```

He metido un try catch para ver que ocurre y me arroja el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por que me arroja eso si lo estoy casteando como Integer y realmente estoy haciendo un conteo de las filas que hay, no tengo ni idea de donde sale el Long ese :(

Estoy usando postman para realizar las llamadas y el resultado que me devuelve la llamada es -1. Que es el valor que le doy a vendidas por defecto. En cuanto a la ruta para hacer el GET está puesta correctamente así es que al menos en eso no esta el error.

La ruta que utilizo es: http://localhost:8080/PruebaREST/webresources/com.jose.pruebarest.entities.entrada/entradasVendidas/1

Muchas Gracias a todos!!!

Comment: El mensaje de error te dice que tienes un problema de Cast. Probablemente se deba a que `getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Entrada e WHERE e.evento = :evento", Integer.class)
            .setParameter("evento", idEvento).getSingleResult()` te este devolviendo un String. Mete ese codigo dentro de un `Integer.ParseInt(...)`